# IE9 behind authenticated proxy prompts for credentials when opening office documents

Tags: security, windows-7, internet-explorer-9, ms-office

I am getting complaints from my users about being prompted for user and password when using Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 to download Office documents from my SSL site.  I have reproduced the problem and it seems to be exactly the problem described in 
[this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/335972/ie9-behind-authenticated-proxy-prompts-for-credentials-when-opening-office-docum) (which has no answers)

It seems like the advice [on this virtual classroom site](http://myusfnews.it.usf.edu/wordpress/?p=663) provides a solution for users, but is there a way for me, as a web developer, to address this issue?

Comment: I think we can all agree that the real security problem here is IE.